# Silverstripe DataObject Relationships - two has_many that relate to each other

Tags: php, silverstripe

I am going a little nuts trying to figure this out, I am sure the solution is simple, but I have real trouble visualising these data relationships. So, here's what I am trying to do:

I have an object called "Offer", which needs two GridFields for "ItineraryItem" and "ItineraryTab" Data Objects

This is what I have at the minute in the three objects, but it is returning an error every time and I can't seem to figure out why.

```
// Offer
$has_many = array(
   "ItineraryItems" => "ItineraryItem",
   "ItineraryTabs" => "ItineraryTab"
);

// On ItineraryTab
$has_one = array(
   "Offer" => "Offer"
);
$many_many = array(
   "ItineraryItems" => "ItineraryItem"
);

// on ItineraryItem
$has_one = array(
   "Offer" => "Offer"
);
$belongs_many_many = array(
   "ItineraryTabs" => "ItineraryTab"
);
```

As I said, the solution is probably pretty simple, but I can't see it anymore after so many hours of trying! Please help me!

I am operating on Silverstripe 3.4, if that helps

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: in an ajax page getting the offer, i get this: SELECT DISTINCT count(DISTINCT "ItineraryItem"."ID") AS "Count"

FROM "ItineraryItem"
INNER JOIN "ItineraryTab_ItineraryItems" ON "ItineraryTab_ItineraryItems"."ItineraryItemID" = "ItineraryItem"."ID"
LEFT JOIN "ItineraryTab" ON "ItineraryTab_ItineraryItems"."ItineraryTabID" = "ItineraryTab"."ID"

WHERE ("OfferID" = ?)
 AND ("ItineraryTab"."TabNo" = ?)

Column 'OfferID' in where clause is ambiguous

Comment: Do you really need to relate the Offer to the Items and Tabs as well as the Items to the Tabs and vice versa? I don't know what these models represent, but it seems overly complex. The error is happening because you've got the same relation alias in two places that reference each other - fix by changing `Offer` to something else like `ItemOffer` or something, but that won't necessarily mean your relationships are set up correctly.

Comment: I am open to suggestions, what I am trying to achieve is that the Itinerary Items on each offer can be grouped into tabs. I was trying to allow the client to create as many tabs as they need with the ItineraryTab object.

Comment: Do you need the item and tabs to be related to each other? Otherwise you could access both of them through the Offer model and remote the cross relationship

Comment: Ideally i need to be able to relate the items and tabs in a way that means that I can select multiple tabs (it is a listbox at the moment) from each Item -- and be able to grab this relationship on the front end to render the results in tabs (if that makes sense)  -- that said, if there is a more efficient way to do this, please let me know

Comment: It looks like the error you're getting is because you didn't specify the table for `OfferID`. I guess this is caused by a query you wrote? Just filter by `"ItineraryItem"."OfferID"`, instead of just `"OfferID"`

Comment: Sadly i think it is coming from Silverstripe itself, i don't actually have any queries that use the offerID as a filter except the core silverstripe functions.

Comment: I think i am going to have to get a workaround going for this, thank you for all of your suggestions though

Answer (score 0):

So, i had to answer this myself, and found something that works -- but i am not sure it is the correct way or if it's a hack. Here it is anyway, in case it helps someone.

First off, i had to get into the database and delete the OfferID column from the Tab object.

```
// Offer.php
$has_many = array(
    'ItineraryItems' => 'ItineraryItem'
);

$many_many = array(
   'ItineraryTabs' => 'ItineraryTab', 
);

//ItineraryItem.php
$has_one = array(
    "Offer" => 'Offer'
);

$many_many = array(
    'ItineraryTabs' => 'ItineraryTab'
);

//ItineraryTab.php
$belongs_many_many = array(
    "ItineraryItems" => "Offer.ItineraryItems"
);
```

If anyone finds something more elegant, please let me know, but this seems to do the job for now.